# What is the best platform for displaying interactive PDFs on a tablet?

Tags: pdf, applications, ipad

We want to produce a series of interactive PDFs which will be viewed on iPads by our employees in a retail environment (in 350+ locations in our region). We are looking for a delivery platform which will give us the following:

- A clean, easy-to-use interface (the less options the better)
- The ability to update these PDFs remotely
- The option to view these PDFs in a 'library'.

We would really like to utilise the interactive and video aspects of interactive PDFs, so ideally the delivery platform would allow this.

Does anyone know of a piece of software (an app or a web-app), or an alternative delivery method that ticks these boxes?

Comment: Rather than use PDFs, my inclination would be to make the files into SVGs, and simply put those on a server somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I still do not have clear what you mean by interactive.

Interactive can be from having a menu and then jumping into a section or asambling a game like 3D model.

A pdf can not be "Updated", you need to download it. But you probably can download just the first file and then link to other resources.

But in reality I would totally go for a web aplication... aka a web page.

Besides that point, the option to realy having control on your pdf is https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/ You can design the pdf somewhere else, but to give it more interaction you need that.

Comment: Hi @rafael - the interactive elements I'm talking about are buttons to link to other pages and URLs, embedded videos, buttons with hover states, etc. I'll be creating the PDFs in InDesign and adding the interactivity in Acrobat DC. By 'updated' I mean I want the ability to be able to replace the PDF with a newer version without physically picking up the iPad. Ideally, a solution that lets us host the file(s) somewhere and replace them, so the user's iPad always links to the most up-to-date version.

Answer (score 0):

If your a little bit into code:

http://codecanyon.net/item/real-3d-flipbook-jquery-plugin/4281720

I use this plugin and it is really awesome on every screen size.